# Dynamically open and filter different reports from a single form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I'm trying to open and filter a report based on the report that a user selects from a combobox in a form. To simplify the example, here's what I'm dealing with:

First I'm opening the report:

```
Dim strReportName As String
strReportName = "General Information"
DoCmd.OpenReport strReportName, acViewPreview
```

This works fine, the problem arrises when I'm trying to apply a filter.

```
With Reports!strReportName
    .Filter = strFilter
    .FilterOn = True
End With
```

The problem I can't find my way around, is that it seems impossible to use a variable reportname in this syntax. Needless to say, the error thrown by VBA is as follows:

```
Run-time error '2451':

The report name 'strReportName' you entered is misspelled or refers to a report that 
isn't open or doesn't exist.
```

My question is: Is there any way to alter this statement into letting me filter the report that's currently open without needing to hardcode the reportnames into VBA?

Comment: the only way I can think of its to [**insert a module programmatically**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978839/dynamically-create-dynamic-arrays-in-vba/18979499#18979499) and replace the strReportName with the actual name. I wouldn't really recommend doing it that way but it's the only solution I am aware of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When *strReportName* is a variable which contains the name of a report, you discovered this fails ..

```vb
With Reports!strReportName
```

Use this instead ...

```vb
With Reports(strReportName)
```

Comment: Why are the biggest braincrackers always so straightforward in the end... Thank you!