# how define a number of arrays in vba dynamically - one array for each file in a folder

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a folder which contains a few excel files.

In each of those files I want to create an array which will contain the data in the "data" sheet. Each workbook or file has this worksheet.

Only problem is there could be a different number of files in the folder each time.

I want to capture the contents of the "data" worksheet of each file in an array each and then write all this data to one single file.

**Question**
Is it possible to dynamically create arrays based on for example the number of files in a folder?

If so how do you create those dynamic arrays?

**Example**
Instead of having one array (which I change the size of) I want to ... 
(depending on the number of files in a folder for example create that many separate arrays?

e.g. 3 files in an folder

dim array01
dim array02
dim array03

Is it better to create one array per workbook in the folder - to store the contents of the "data" worksheet, or create one larger array?

Comment: `ReDim Preserve somearray(intLargerThanBefore)`

Comment: Ok I get that you can change the size of an array with the ReDim Preserve, but HOW do you change the Number of arrays?

Comment: You could make a Multi-Dimensional array? See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369217/redim-preserve-to-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-visual-basic-6)

Comment: I think you want a multi-dimensional array. So array(0,1) would be the first file in the 0th folder etc.

Comment: if there are two files in the multidimensional array, how do you access the elements (columns, rows) of the data in the first file? Normally I would do a loop with ubound(array,1) ubound(array,2)?

Comment: actually to better describe it - how would I access the data value in the second file, the first column and the third row of data in that second file using array syntax?

Comment: somehow related: [Dynamically create dynamic arrays in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978839/dynamically-create-dynamic-arrays-in-vba/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a multi-dimensional array and redim it all the time, consider storing each data array in a `Collection`like this:

```
Dim allData As Collection, data As Variant, file As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet


Set allData = New Collection
file = Dir("c:\testfolder\*.xlsx")
While (file <> "")
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(file)
    data = wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Cells  'Adjust this to get your data range
    allData.Add data, file
    file = Dir
Wend
```

Later you can use a `For Each` loop to retrieve the data:

```
Dim count As Integer
For Each data In allData
    count = count + 1
    Debug.Print "Dataset #" & count & " has " & _
        UBound(data, 1) & " x " & UBound(data, 2) & " entries"
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Sub MAIN()
   Dim FolderOfInterest As String, i As Long
    FolderOfInterest = "C:\TestFolder"
   Dim ary()
    ary = files_in_folder(FolderOfInterest)
   MsgBox "There are " & UBound(ary) & " files in folder " & FolderOfInterest
   '
   '  Now store the array in a worksheet column
'
i = 1
For Each a In ary
   Cells(i, "A").Value = a
  i = i + 1
Next a
End Sub

Public Function files_in_folder(folderS As String) As Variant
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set folder = fso.GetFolder(folderS)
   ReDim temp(1 To folder.Files.Count)

   i = 1
   For Each file In folder.Files
   temp(i) = file.Name
  i = i + 1
  Next file

   files_in_folder = temp
End Function
```